# What is the composition of diet coke?

Tags: food-chemistry, composition

I've been trying to find the values of any sort of percentage composition of diet coke and I haven't found any luck other than one interviewee (Dr. MAUREEN STOREY [Senior Vice President, Science Policy, American Beverage Association]) who states

> Soda is comprised mostly of water. A full-calorie soft drink has 90 percent water, and a diet soft drink is 99 percent water. Water is the most important nutrient that we have...

And that was all the information I have.

Comment: Is not energy content published on any drink bottle/can ? 1 g of sugar is equivalent to about 4.3 kcal, or about 4.2 times more kJ. // Referring cal as calorie ( "small calorie") and kcal=1000 cal as Calorie ( "big calorie" ) is very old and deprecated way to do so. Calorie itself is a deprecated, but tolerable unit among old school chemists.

Comment: Soda being 99 percent water is high questionable. Sweet sodas are at about 30% sugars by mass (!) Diet zero soda might approach that as for the CO2 content was calculated here in SE to be a few gram per liter soda.

Comment: I edited your question. One would not "boil a soda" to find it's caloric content. You might not understand what is meant by calorie content of a soft drink. The caloric content refers to the energy content (in kcal) of nutrients that a person can use to derive energy, for instance fat, carbs and even protein. Diet soda is diet soda because the sweeteners have a much higher sweetness than sugars such as sucrose or glucose. That means you hardly need sweetener, and therefore energy content is very low.

Comment: It is a pity the question is closed. Because the formula of Coca-Cola contains 16 ingredients. They are described in page 422 of the book by Mark Pendergrast, "For God, Country and Coca-Cola", Phoenix, London 1994. ISBN 1 85799 180 X. There is not enough room in this "Comment" to be more precise and give more details.

Comment: @Maurice is the fact that the recipe is treated as industrial top secret a legend?

Comment: @Alchimista. The Coke formula is known by 3 persons. In Coca-Cola factories, the constituants are called "Material X1 or M2". So the workers mix unknown liquids. The discovery of the formula is a rather long story covering about 10 pages, where the author explains that its research took many years. He said at the end that he told the Head of the Company that he knows the formula. The President was not impressed. He said it is not easy to copy the formula, because for example one of the constituant is described by "oil of unripe orange flowers". But what does it mean : "unripe flower" ?

Comment: The water content was bracketed as 99.3% on the ingredients list for some cans being sold in the UK.

Comment: Water and bad stuff.

Answer (score 4):

**The major ingredients in diet coke vary by country but none are major components compared to sugar in full-fat drinks**

The exact ingredient list of Diet Coke is not publically available but most of the flavourings are present in very low quantities. Also, the exact recipe varies over time and across countries (this is claimed to be an adaptation for local tastes). So it is hard to be exact

The major difference between a ~330 mL can of Diet Coke and normal (sugary) Coke is huge. Sugary Coke has about 40g of sugar for reference (other ingredients will be present in amounts similar to Diet Coke). The major components are:

- sweetener (usually aspartame but others are sometimes mixed in at similar levels): ~100mg
- caffeine: ~40mg
- citric acid (or citrate): ~50mg
- phosphoric acid (or phosphate): ~100mg

The total mass of water, for comparison, is about 330g (330,000mg) so there really isn't much of any of those key ingredients relative to the water.

This is very different to the sugary version of the drink where the sweetener is more than 10% of the total mass of the drink.

Comment: Full fat or sugar rich?

Comment: @Alchimista In normal, casual conversation "full fat" is a synonym for normal, sugary Coke.

Comment: ah focus is on the side effects. Got it.

Answer (score 4):

The major ingredient in Diet Coke is water (H$_2$O). The second ingredient is carbon dioxide (CO$_2$), about 30 psig, or three times atmospheric pressure. (I measured it with an automobile tire gauge.) Since CO$_2$ is soluble about 1.7 g/Kg at 20$^o$C at atmospheric pressure, Ref 1, this is about 5 g/L, or ~0.5%, using a density for Diet Coke of 1 g/L Ref 2.

[image]

So, in the list of ingredients for Diet Coke, Ref 3, everything will be between a maximum of 0.5%, down to about 0.01295% ("46 mg caffeine/12 fl oz" on the label of my 2L bottle).

And, as Matt Black noted, the recipe varies from country to country, and from time to time (and is noticeably different in cans vs fountain delivery, according to those with highly developed preferences), but the big impacts are provided by

#1. water

#2. carbon dioxide

#3. artificial sweetener

#4. caffeine and

#5. flavoring, which might include a little more acid, like citric or phosphoric.

Seltzer is just #1 plus #2; many caffeine-free beverages just leave out #4.

Ref 1. https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/gases-solubility-water-d_1148.html

Ref 2. [http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~lecturedemonstrations/Composer/Pages/36.34.html](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Electuredemonstrations/Composer/Pages/36.34.html)

Ref 3. https://www.coca-cola.ca/brands/diet-coke; see also https://www.huffpost.com/entry/coke-zero-sugar-taste-difference_n_597f71d7e4b00bb8ff3875d9 for varieties of Diet Coke

Comment: This needs a bit a MathJax love. On my phone the formatting breaks. But I'm not going to try to fix this using my phone... It'll only become worse.